# Print the google map with the markers

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have trying to print the page that contains a google map and some markers. I found in internet about how to print the page. But it is only printing the google map not the markers inside the map.

This is the code that I have tried so far. I am not sure where I did mistake.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="button-container">
            <a href="#" id="PrintDiv" class="btn btn-success btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>Print</a>
        </div>

        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#PrintDiv').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        var contents = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
        var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
        frame1.name = "frame1";
        frame1.style.position = "absolute";
        frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
        document.body.appendChild(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        return false;
    })
})
var beaches = [
    ["Place A", 21.984606, 89.974250],
    ["West Bengal", 21.681855, 88.584980],
    ["Sea Beach", 21.617401, 87.500898]
];
var markers = [];
var map; //set scope here so various functions can use them

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[0][1], beaches[0][2]),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(beaches[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
        markers.push(marker);
    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid printing is not supported in Google Maps JavaScript API. Please have a look at the following answer in the Google Maps FAQ:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#print

It reads

> Printing from the JavaScript API is not supported. This is because printing support is inconsistent across commonly used browsers. We recommend using the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro) for printing purposes.

Based on the FAQ answer and your code sample I believe you should generate the following static maps URL and print the resulting image

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=800x800&maptype=roadmap&markers=label%3A1%7C21.984606%2C89.974250&markers=label%3A2%7C21.681855%2C88.584980&markers=label%3A3%7C21.617401%2C87.500898&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

```html
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=800x800&maptype=roadmap&markers=label%3A1%7C21.984606%2C89.974250&markers=label%3A2%7C21.681855%2C88.584980&markers=label%3A3%7C21.617401%2C87.500898&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&signature=wwmJyiXitiZNdkisy3P4qsRKj64=" />
```

I hope this helps!